# Why I get so many NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsnotificationcenter

Did anybody experience the same. I got a lots of notification sometimes. It seems I got into an infinite loop.

Is there any way to filter and listen only to my own settings value, that I wish to listen?

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [center addObserverForName:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil
        queue:mainQueue
        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            SettingsManager * s = [SettingsManager sharedSettings];
                DLog(@"\n%@ Setting logging: %@", note, s.loggingEnabled ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                if (s.loggingEnabled) {
                    [BPAnalytic startLogging];
                } else {
                    [BPAnalytic stopLogging];
                }
            }
     ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not removing observer. Thats why. try removing observer on dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: The observer is added in my application delegate. I removed it when the application is closed. Thats a code synopsis from my applicationDidLaunchWithOptions.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the case when another 3rd party component in my app was writing changes to the NSUserDefaults without me knowing. You may want to scrutinize any such components/libraries to see if this is happening

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I finally figured out what was happening! In my case it was the Crashlytics framework making changes to the defaults.